# pytest AttributeError when using fixture with yield

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest fixture with yield. But receive AttributeError when trying to get value that yield returns

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture()
def driver_setup():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

basetest.py

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_setup")
class BaseTest:
    pass
```

test_example.py

```
class TestExample(BaseTest):

    def test_example(self):
        self.driver.get(url)
        pass
```

Output: `AttributeError: 'TestExample' object has no attribute 'driver'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update `driver_setup` fixture as below if you want access to `driver` in tests.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def driver_setup(request):
    driver = webdriver
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

For more details refer to http://computableverse.com/blog/pytest-sharing-class-fixtures.