# Attribute error when testing Flask with PyTest fixture

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

Can someone explain how I could use the pytest fixtures in my tests?

I have been given this `conftest.py` where it defines 3 pytest fixtures:

```
{...}

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def app(request):
    app = create_app({
        'TESTING': True
    })
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    def teardown():
        ctx.pop()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return app

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def client(app, request):
    return app.test_client()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def get(client):
    return humanize_werkzeug_client(client.get)
```

I am trying to test my app using the above test fixtures. Based on my undersanding, I need to use that `app` fixture in my pytests. As seen in this [blog](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/), I have tried something like this:

```
def test_myflaskapp(app):
    response = app.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

But I get an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'get'`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47108331/6003691) did not make any sense to me I am afraid not sure if it even applies on my case.

Can someone explain how/what I am doing wrong? I am trying to learn `Flask`/`PyTest` and I cannot find an example/guide that explains how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app` fixture returns a `Flask` instance, I think you want to use `.get` method on the [test client instance](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_client). Try changing `app` to `client` in your test.

Check out [the official docs on testing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/).